# When anywhere on the body is clicked, different sentences should pop up in the mouse location

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create an interactive website where the user is able to click on any section of a blank screen and the text will show up in that exact position where the user clicks. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone knows how to do this. Every time the user clicks, a new sentence appears and there's only so many times you can click the page.

```
var quotes = ["quote1", "quote2"];
var current = 0;

function changeQuote() {
  if (current >= quotes.length) current = 0;
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML(quotes[current]);
  current++;
}

document.body.onclick = changeQuote;
```

This is what I started with but this doesn't seem to working, would I need an EventListener and how would I go about this?

Comment: When having a blank screen, the height of `body` is 0, you can't click it. Store a reference to the paragraph element into a variable (`popup` in the latter example) outside of the click handler, and set CSS `position: fixed` for it. Then attach the click event to `document` instead of `body`, and add something like `popup.style.transform = \`translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px\`;` in your click handler. Don't forget to include `e` in the formal arguments of the click handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = e; //get the click position

  //create the div    
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  //set its text
  div.innerText = 'some text';

  //set its position and position style
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = clientX + 'px';
  div.style.top = clientY + 'px';

  document.body.append(div);//add div to the page
})
```